# Getting inconsistent tab delimiter width when pasting from Google docs spreadsheet

Tags: parsing, csv, google-sheets

I am trying to create a gadget for some people, where all they need to do is really copy the contents of a spreadsheet, then paste it in a textbox, which will in turn create a nice table for them to embed in their articles.

I managed to do everything, however Google docs, when copying and pasting data in a text editor, seems to get the size (width) of the tab delimiter wrong between values. So, instead of getting 4 spaces that is the default, i am getting 2 in some cases and so far i managed to find out that the reason is that some of the cells contain strings with spaces. For some reason, this seems to confuse Google docs, thus supplying wrong spacings, which in turn, ruin my script.

I know i can use comma separated values here, but the issue is we are trying to give people the ability to simply copy and paste. Look at the example output below:

```
School Name Location    Type    No. eligible pupils
```

In this example, School Name is one cell, Location is another, Type is another and No. eligible pupils is the last one. It is clear that the first cell does not have the necessary space on the right.

Any ideas? I thought about converting all blank spaces that take more than 1 space to commas, but this might lead to a situation users might actually use 2... which would not work again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, it was the code editor that was actually not showing the tabs right. Using a regexp and another code editor (vim) showed that all of them were actual tabs. :)